# What is the difference between both by/after

Tags: prepositions

By+gerund
After+gerund

Provide some examples too.

Sometimes they mean the same I guess or don't they?

Any help will be appreciated. :)

I'm not a native speaker so I'm confused with both.

Comment: Do you have any examples that are confusing you?

Comment: Is this sentence right? He is trying to become cool by insulting me in front of my girlfriend

Answer (score 0):

> He is trying to become cool *by insulting* me in front of my girlfriend.

is correct.

Comment: But how? By is used for method . Aint it?